# Can I automate the PowerShell Extension package installation?

Tags: powershell-extensions, sitecore-install-framework, installation, packages, module

Is it possible to automate the installation of the package that everybody is using to automate the other packages installation?

My goal would be having a script which I can use to install SPE on a given Sitecore instance.

Edit to clarify question:

How can I automate the installation of the Sitecore PowerShell Extensions module when I install Sitecore?

Comment: Is it related to Sitecore SIF ?

Comment: @SitecoreSam it would be if somebody tells me that there is this magic method on SIF that I can use to archive my goal here :p

Comment: have a look at http://www.rockpapersitecore.com/2017/11/using-sif-to-install-sitecore-packages/

Comment: Take a look on Sitecore HabitatHome.Utilities repo. Especially this part https://github.com/Sitecore/Sitecore.HabitatHome.Utilities/blob/develop/XP/install/install-modules.ps1

Comment: Did you try this guide??????: https://doc.sitecorepowershell.com/installation/contributor-guide#single-instance-for-sitecore-8-and-9

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't look like an automated thing. A lot of manual steps there...

Comment: Looks like you want installer, but you said you will write script which installs it. So all steps for script are described under guide above. Write script and you have automated installation. Then invoke your script after installing Sitecore - you need use SIF anyway, and it's done.